# Multiply a (N,N) matrix by a (N,M,O) matrix along the O dimension with Numba

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, numba

I'm trying to multiply a matrix A of size $(N,N)$ by a matrix B of size $(N,M,O)$ matrix along the O dimension (that is, left-multiply all the "pages" of B along the O dimension by A), using a jitted numba function.

I have come up with this solution:

```
@njit
def fast_expectation(Pi, X):
    
    res = np.empty_like(X)
    
    for i in range(Pi.shape[0]):
        for j in range(X.shape[1]):
            for k in range(X.shape[2]):
                res[i,j,k] = np.dot(Pi[i,:], X[:,j,k])
                            
    return res
```

However, this returns a warning `NumbaPerformanceWarning: np.dot() is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, A))`. Do you know how I could perform this in a fast way, with a numba compatible function?

I tried running the previous code, and swapping the arrays of the matrix B (turn it into a (N,M,O) matrix). Didn't work.

Edit:

I also tried the following code:

```
@njit
def multiply_ith_dimension(Pi, i, X):
    """If Pi is a matrix, multiply Pi times the ith dimension of X and return"""
    X = np.swapaxes(X, 0, i)
    shape = X.shape
    X = X.reshape(shape[0], -1)

    # iterate forward using Pi
    X = Pi @ X

    # reverse steps
    X = X.reshape(Pi.shape[0], *shape[1:])
    return np.swapaxes(X, 0, i)
```

which also gives me an error

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
reshape() supports contiguous array only
...
    <source elided>
    shape = X.shape
    X = X.reshape(shape[0], -1)
    ^
```

Comment: Could you try using column-major ordering for the variable Pi? e.g. before the loop, insert the line `Pi = np.asfortranarray(Pi)` to change from row-major to column-major. Don't change the indexing.

Comment: Thanks! It works if I apply it to X instead! 

However, when I pass the transpose of Pi (`Pi.T`), I get the previous error again... `NumbaPerformanceWarning: np.dot() is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, F))` 
Do you know how to make it work in both cases?

Comment: If you need row-major order, you can use `np.ascontiguousarray()` on the Pi variable to force that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this returns a warning `NumbaPerformanceWarning: np.dot() is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, A))`

This is because you access a **row-major** Numpy array using `X[:,j,k]`. The last dimension is contiguous but not the first. You can fix that using a **transposition**. That being said, the Numpy **transposition does not create a new array**. Instead, it creates a **view** with strides. You can force a contiguous array to be created using **`np.ascontiguousarray`**. Alternatively, you can just explicitly copy the array. For example: `arr.T.copy()`.

An alternative solution is simply not to use `np.dot` but plain loops instead. Loops are generally very efficient in Numba while calling Numpy function can introduce some overheads (mainly due to allocations, temporary arrays or implicit casting).

> which also gives me an error `[...] reshape() supports contiguous array only`

AFAIK, this is a current limitation of Numba. Numpy can do that correctly (at least I got no issue on my machine with Numpy 1.22.4). This is certainly because Numba want the result to be always a view while Numpy can actually return a copy in some cases (typically like this one).

---

Note your first Numba code is inefficient because it is sequential and naive (no tiling, unrolling or anything like this). `A @ B` is generally very efficient because it makes use of a BLAS library. BLAS like OpenBLAS (default implementation on most platform) or the Intel MKL libraries are highly optimised since decades by expert of the domain. They use multiple thread if possible and use a much more complex optimized code (typically using SIMD instruction manually in C).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up writing a big for loop to compute this matrix multiplication. There is a small cost, but it still seem better than before.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with `np.einsum` (or even faster, the `opt_einsum` library).

`result = np.einsum('ab,bcd->acd', A, B, optimize=True)`

Note, `einsum` uses `np.dot` under the hood (which is based on BLAS), so is probably the fastest possible approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, `np.einsum` is not compatible with Numba, as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you had to do it explicitly in numba. In numba, best would be to use np.dot which calls a BLAS implementation.

Comment: This is what I do, but it returns the mentioned warning.